# iOS Nested Context slower on Device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to move from one `NSManagedContext` to multiple via nested context.

I'm using those article to help me :

- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/
- http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/the-concurrent-core-data-stack

#### Actual System

```
[myHTTPClient getPath:path
  parameters:@{access_token & stuff}
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject)
    {
      // filling the dic in a NSManagedObject
    }
    [myMainContext save:&error];
  }, failure:failureBlock];
```

#### Wanted System

```
[myHTTPClient getPath:path
  parameters:@{access_token & stuff}
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *writerObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] writerManagedObjectContext];
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    temporaryContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

    [temporaryContext performBlock:^{
      for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject)
      {
        // filling the dic in a NSManagedObject
      }
      [temporaryContext save:&error];
      [managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        [writerObjectContext performBlock:^{
          [writerObjectContext save:&error];
        }];
      }];
    }];
  }, failure:failureBlock];
```

**Diagram**

[image: Parent-Context Diagram]

#### Problem

I had problems saving my data while using this method but I solved it (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151827/coredata-writermanagedobjectcontext-freeze-when-save)

However, as I said in the previous question, it **speed up 2 times** on the simulator but it's like **5x slower** on a device. I use iPod Touch 4th to test.

How is it possible and how can I improve that ?
I'm not against using this diagram :

[image: Shared Persistent Store Diagram]

But I want to find out HOW to integrate that in my code because I tried and it changed nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Without more information this question is pretty broad but you should probably try merging changes as in [Stack #3](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout) rather than saving up and see if this improves performance on a device. The optimal Core Data stack depends on your use-cases.

Comment: I think that it's the actual system I use ... And it's not so good. If you want more info, tell me and I'll put it. Anyway, my "use-case" is the following : I'm getting data from a Web-service with AFHTTPClient and keeping it in Core Data. I have 10 calls that are between 1 and 50 objects (**low**) and 1 call that is often between 10 and 40K objects (**heavy**) and I need to find a way to speed up the save of those objects because it takes like 5 minutes ...